# Add object to NSMUtable Array Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a shared singleton class`NSMutableArray`  `[ICGlobals sharedApplianceCount]`(first time using this pattern so bear with me if ive done something really silly here)

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ICGlobals : NSObject

{

NSMutableArray* applianceCount;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *applianceCount;

+ (ICGlobals *)sharedApplianceCount;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ICGlobals.h"

@implementation ICGlobals

static ICGlobals *sharedApplianceCount = nil;


+ (ICGlobals *)sharedUser {
if(sharedApplianceCount == nil){
    sharedApplianceCount = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
  }
return sharedApplianceCount;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
return [self sharedApplianceCount];
}
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
return self;
}
@end
```

In "another view controller" im trying to add the `row count` of my `table view` (changeable amount of rows) = `self.circuits.count`

Having tried this

`[[ICGlobals sharedApplianceCount] addObject: self.circuits.count,nil]];`

and

```
[[ICGlobals sharedApplianceCount]   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[[ICGlobals sharedApplianceCount] addObject: self.circuits.count,Nil]];
```

I get no visible @interface error saying my singleton class declares the selector

same with

```
NSNumber* numberOfRows = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.circuits.count];

[[ICGlobals sharedApplianceCount]addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:numberOfRows, nil]];
```

and with

```
[ICGlobals sharedApplianceCount] = self.circuits.count;
```

I get expression assignable. Singleton class has been imported.

Comment: Are trying to make a singleton ?

Comment: trying to add objetcs to it in another view controller

Answer (score 1):

You have an inconsistency in your interface declaration. You declare ivar of type `NSMutableArray` and then a `NSString` property. Firstable, you don't need to declare ivar, declaring a property does it for you. So your interface should look like:

```
@interface ICGlobals : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *applianceCount;

+ (ICGlobals *)sharedApplianceCount;

@end
```

Furthermore, you have a naming glitch. You should not use name `applianceCount` for an array. In general, naming convention of `Cocoa` suggests that `count` should be a number (`int` or `NSUInteger`). I would change this property name to `applianceCounts`.

Then, when you initialize your singletone, you can also initialize the array:

```
+ (ICGlobals *)sharedUser 
{
    if(sharedApplianceCount == nil)
    {
        sharedApplianceCount = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        sharedApplianceCount.applianceCounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedApplianceCount;
}
```

Finally, here is how to add data to your singletone's `applianceCounts` array from view controller.

```
NSNumber* numberOfRows = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.circuits.count];

[[ICGlobals sharedApplianceCount].applianceCounts addObject:numberOfRows];
```

This should point you to right direction.
I don't fully get what you are trying to achieve like I don't understand why you want to have an array there, so if you need further help please let me know in the comments.

I fully recommend you reading about naming conventions. A good start is this article:

[Introduction to Coding Guidelines for Cocoa.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that to me, first time with singleton and thats a great example.  Im storing the row count in an array so I can use this figure for a calculation in another view/s. (and learn about singletons) If theres a more efficent way of doing then I would explore that.  Using app dleegate seem frowned upon

Comment: Getting:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[ICGlobals sharedApplianceCount]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x18b330' using the above code?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend some refactoring to your class. 
First you make the interface like this:

```
@interface ICGlobals : NSObject
// add the app count but make it private, because you will provide methods to access it
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *applianceCount;

// return ICGlobals instance 
+ (ICGlobals)sharedCounter;

- (NSInteger)count;
- (void)addObject:(id)object;
```

now in .m file

```
@implementation ICGlobals

static ICGlobals *sharedApplianceCount = nil;
// this is your method, just changed the name
+ (ICGlobals *)sharedCounter {
if(sharedApplianceCount == nil){
    sharedApplianceCount = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
  }
return sharedApplianceCount;
}

// instance methods goes here 
- (NSInteger)count
{
    return _applicationCount.count;
}

- (void)addObject:(id)object
{
    [_applicationCount addObject:object];
}
```

Now call `[[ICGlobals sharedCount]addObject:object]` from any viewController

Comment: This gives me <ICglobals2: 0x17571850> in my log.  I have changed @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *applianceCount; to a mustabel array and + (ICGlobals)sharedCounter; to + (ICGlobals*)sharedCounter;

Comment: No `+ (ICGlobals)sharedCounter;` needs *,  @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *applianceCount; I think needs to be Mutable array?  `[[ICGlobals sharedCount]addObject:object]` needs to be  `[[ICGlobals sharedCounter]addObject:object]` Done those but just get `<ICGlobals: 0xc1134d0>` when logged